# Right click in Flash, why does it crash?

Tags: firefox, flash, browser-plugin

This has been bugging me for so long that i already learned to accept it as something unavoidable. I had this problem on Windows 7, 8, 8.1 on different hardware and Firefox- and Flash player versions.

**Best case scenario** 
Usually happens when you just started a fresh browser session and accidentally right click in a flash object.
Right-click menu pops up, the image (in a video or a game) freezes but the sound/gameplay continues, after a few seconds you can unfreeze the image by left-clicking any empty area to clear the menu pop-up and the image resumes refreshing as usual. Additionally, in games the button pressed at the time of rightclicking will be stuck and the only way of unsticking it is to repeat the freezing with the same button held.
**Average case** Happens during normal browser usage.
Right-clicking any flash object will freeze Firefox for around 5-20 seconds, it will not react to any input, but other programs can be operated without problems. After that you get a popup informing you that the Flash plugin is not reacting and offers you the choice between `Continue` and `Stop plugin`.
Continuing will keep Firefox frozen and after some time you will be presented with the same choice again.
Stopping the plugin will kill all flash objects across all opened Firefox windows and tabs

Why does it happen?
Is there a way to stop it from happening?

Here is a [Crash report](https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/82026889-d1af-4f66-b07b-19c952150305) that i generated just now, not sure how to interpret it though.

**Edit**
As suggested by Tetsujin, i went to [this Adobe help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html) where i could rightclick the flash window without problems and disable the hardware acceleration. This doesnt seem to solve my problem though, on [that Adobe help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/video-playback-issues.html#main_Solve_video_playback_issues) which also suggests disabling the HW-acceleartion, albeit for a different reason, rightclicking the flash window crashes the plugin as usual. I took a look at the source and found the [location of the flash element](https://helpx.adobe.com/content/help/en/flash-player/kb/video-playback-issues/jcr%3Acontent/main-pars/procedure_0/proc_par/step_0/step_par/flash_0/file.res/settings_icon.swf), going there directly i can rightclick it without causing a crash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the 'simple' solution is to switch off hardware acceleration…

However, to do that the easy way requires you to right-click any Flash image/movie & disable from the [Global Settings](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/891337).

If you can't get that far, then you might try disabling hardware acceleration for the entire machine, at least to see if it will let you get to the Flash settings [WikiHow link](http://www.wikihow.com/Turn-off-Hardware-Acceleration), with caveats that it may not work on newer machines.